# generate mockup using bogus

Tags: .net, mockups, bogus

I have a tricky issue.

I'm writing a tool where a user can pass the source code of a C# model as input and it will  return mockups (n instances with random content).

The question is: Based on this implementation, what are your suggestions to fix the issue described below, or eventally what other solution or framework would you propose instead?

I created a dummy class for testing it and the result is inconsistant:
it correctly generates random values but country does not match the address, fullname does not march firstname + lastname etc..

[image]

The idea of the below code is that the class is not known at compilation time because the class to mockup is initially passed as input text). Using Roslyn, I dynamically compile and load it, then pass it to bugus. For clarity, I'm not exposing the code that calls CSharpCompilation.Create.

In Bogus, If I know in advance the name of the fields, I can do something like this:

```
   .RuleFor(u => u.FirstName, (f, u) => f.Name.FirstName(u.Gender))
   .RuleFor(u => u.LastName, (f, u) => f.Name.LastName(u.Gender))
   .RuleFor(u => u.UserName, (f, u) => f.Internet.UserName(u.FirstName, u.LastName))
```

But In my case, I'm processing the fields one by one and I don't know if they are correlated. For instance, If I process a field named UserName, I eventually don't know if the class has 2 other fields named FirstName and LastName and if they have been already mockuped.

Here is the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using Bogus;

namespace MockupEngine
{
public class MockupGenerator
{
    private int _rowId = 0;
    public List<object> GenerateMockup<T>(int count) where T : class, new()
    {
        _rowId = 0;
        var faker = new Faker<T>()
            .StrictMode(false)
            .Rules((f, o) =>
            {
                foreach (var property in o.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    FillProperyData(f, o, property);
                }
            });

        var mockupList = new List<object>();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var mockup = faker.Generate();
            mockupList.Add(mockup);
        }
        return mockupList;
    }
    private void FillProperyData<T>(Faker f, T o, PropertyInfo property)
    {
        string propertyName = property.Name;
        if (property.GetCustomAttribute<ObsoleteAttribute>() != null)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (FieldSynonymous.Synonymous.ContainsKey(propertyName))
        {
            FillProperyDataForDictionaryEntries(f, o, property, FieldSynonymous.Synonymous[propertyName]);
            return;
        }

        if (property.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
        {
            property.SetValue(o, f.Random.Bool());
        }
        if (property.PropertyType == typeof(int))
        {
            property.SetValue(o, f.Random.Int());
        }
        else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            property.SetValue(o, f.Random.AlphaNumeric(10));
        }
        else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
        {
            property.SetValue(o, f.Date.Past());
        }
        else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(double))
        {
            property.SetValue(o, f.Random.Double());
        }
        // add more types as needed
    }
    private void FillProperyDataForDictionaryEntries<T>(Faker f, T o, PropertyInfo property, string propertyName)
    {
        object? result = null;
        switch (propertyName)
        {
            case "Id":
                result = _rowId++;
                break;
            case "Address":
                result = f.Address.FullAddress();
                break;
            case "Street":
                result = f.Address.StreetName();
                break;
            case "BuildingNumber":
                result = f.Address.BuildingNumber();
                break;
            case "ZipCode":
                result = f.Address.ZipCode();
                break;
            case "City":
                result = f.Address.City();
                break;
            case "Country":
                result = f.Address.Country();
                break;
            case "CountryCode":
                result = f.Address.CountryCode();
                break;
            case "Price":
                result = f.Commerce.Price();
                break;
            case "Categories":
                result = f.Commerce.Categories(1).First();
                break;
            case "ProductName":
                result = f.Commerce.ProductName();
                break;
            case "Company":
                result = f.Company.CompanyName();
                break;
            case "Date":
                result = f.Date.Past(2);
                break;
            case "Month":
                result = f.Date.Month();
                break;
            case "EmailAddress":
                result = f.Internet.ExampleEmail();
                break;
            case "AccountName":
                result = f.Internet.ExampleEmail();
                break;
            case "Currency":
                result = f.Finance.Currency();
                break;
            case "CreditCardNumber":
                result = f.Finance.CreditCardNumber();
                break;
            case "IpAddress":
                result = f.Internet.IpAddress();
                break;
            case "Password":
                result = f.Internet.Password(10);
                break;
            case "Url":
                result = f.Internet.Url();
                break;
            case "Text":
                result = f.Random.AlphaNumeric(10);
                break;
            case "Lorem":
                result = f.Lorem.Text();
                break;
            case "FirstName":
                result = f.Name.FirstName();
                break;
            case "LastName":
                result = f.Name.LastName();
                break;
            case "FullName":
                result = f.Name.FullName();
                break;
            case "Prefix":
                result = f.Name.Prefix();
                break;
            case "Suffix":
                result = f.Name.Suffix();
                break;
            case "JobTitle":
                result = f.Name.JobTitle();
                break;
            case "PhoneNumber":
                result = f.Phone.PhoneNumber();
                break;
            case "FileName":
                result = f.System.FileName();
                break;
            case "FileType":
                result = f.System.FileType();
                break;
            case "FileExtension":
                result = f.System.FileExt();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        if (result == null)
        {
            result = f.Lorem.Text();
        }
        ConvertResult(property, o, result);
    }
    private void ConvertResult<T>(PropertyInfo property, T o, object result)
    {
        Type resultType = result.GetType();
        if (property.PropertyType == resultType)
        {
            property.SetValue(o, result);
            return;
        }
        if (property.PropertyType == typeof(bool))
        {
            bool success = bool.TryParse(result.ToString(), out bool bResult);
            if (success == true)
            {
                property.SetValue(o, bResult);
            }
        }
        if (property.PropertyType == typeof(int))
        {
            bool success = int.TryParse(result.ToString(), out int iResult);
            if (success == true)
            {
                property.SetValue(o, iResult);
            }
        }
        else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(string))
        {
            property.SetValue(o, result.ToString());
        }
        else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
        {
        }
        else if (property.PropertyType == typeof(double))
        {
            bool success = double.TryParse(result.ToString(), out double dResult);
            if (success == true)
            {
                property.SetValue(o, dResult);
            }
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
}
```

}

Synonymous is a dictionnary that allows me to guess what builtin bogus function to call based on the name of the field.

```
    public static Dictionary<string, string> Synonymous = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        {"Id","Id" },
        {"RowId","Id" },
        {"Address", "Address"},
        {"FullAddress", "Address"},
        {"PrincipalAddress", "Address"},
        {"BuildingAddress", "Address"},
        {"Location", "Address"},
        {"AddressLine1", "Address"},
        {"AddressLine2", "Address"},
        {"Address1", "Address"},
        {"Address2", "Address"},
```